# Lightweight version of R and shiny for efficient app deployment?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to make the R + shiny build smaller, so as to make it more light weight when deploying shiny apps? (or plumber API's, or any other R processes for that matter?)

#### Background

I have been deploying shiny apps in kubernetes and the builds are quite a lot larger than similar apps written in other languages (e.g. python).

I've also deployed some to [heroku](https://steve-condylios.medium.com/how-to-move-your-r-shiny-app-on-to-the-web-using-heroku-fd54b7d2ad88), and they're also quite large builds (in the hundreds of MB, whereas other similar apps in other languages might only be a few tens of MB).

#### What I know so far

I know base R is quite large, but packages are the bulk of the build size, so I have reduced those as much as possible by not importing anything unnecessary, and extracting some functions from their packages so as to not have to include the whole thing.

Comment: I do not know about lightweight shiny version. In my opinion, this is the worst property of R (and shiny is worse) as it requires a lots of packages and system libraries. 
Packaging your app with the littlest requirement (`@importFrom` in roxygen2) shall help, resulting in a package archive. Also, I usually dockerize my app for reproducibility aim which can make the app heavier.

Comment: [r-minimal](https://github.com/r-hub/r-minimal) might be of interest - The Docker images are based on Alpine Linux. See `r-minimal/examples/shiny/`.

Comment: 1. What base image are you using for your existing container solution. 2. What R packages do you rely on?

Comment: [Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2017q4/002024.html) a related discussion can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I think [leprechaun](https://github.com/devOpifex/leprechaun/tree/master/docs) is the best option (as in easy AND light) out there right now. It's purpose is to be similar to golem, but without making the heavy requirements of golem. (link to the docs https://github.com/devOpifex/leprechaun/tree/master/docs)

Comment: Would you mind explaining how `library(leprechaun)` saves diskspace? To me it seems `leprechaun` claims to be leaner than `golem` - However `golem` isn't mentioned @stevec's question. The above is a 'link-only-answers'.

Comment: Sorry for the sparse answer, what I meant is that a lot of shiny apps are made using golem (which is super heavy on terms of dependencies, and thus disk space, loading, etc..).

The OP also says that he is *extracting some functions from their packages so as to not have to include the whole thing.* and that's what leprechaun helps to do.